# Transloadit : Can't submit the form with :autoSubmit => false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transloadit

I am using `transloadit gem` for my rails app. I just included what https://github.com/transloadit/rails-sdk this gem show to do.

I have a form which contained other attribute as well with Image attribute. 
So I added:

```
<%= transloadit_jquerify "upload", **:autoSubmit => false**, 
:processZeroFiles => false, :triggerUploadOnFileSelection => true %>.
```

Because of `triggerUploadOnFileSelection => true` I got `transloadit` popup with progress bar when I select image by browse button and its added textarea with `transloadit` name.

But when I submit the form by hitting the submit button. It shows me `transloadit` popup with progress bar again and after that they include new hidden textarea with `transloadit` name. This thing happened again n again whenever I hit the submit button and can't submit the form with image.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just remove the `triggerUploadonFileSelection` or set it to `false` and that your files will be submitted when you click submit.

Transloadit Support.